# Propagator for a massless scalar field in $d$-dimensional spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions, propagator

I'm trying to show that for a free massless scalar field, the 2-point correlation function in $d$-dimensional spacetime has the following form:
$$<\phi(x)\phi(y)> = \int \frac{d^d{p}}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{i e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}}{p^2+i\epsilon}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d-2}{2}\right)}{4\pi^{d/2}|x-y|^{d-2}}.$$

I've seen similar solutions for this problem on the forum, but they've only been applicable for $d=4$. My attempt goes as follows

$$ \int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{i  e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}}{p^2 - m^2 +i \epsilon}   =\int \frac{dp^0}{2\pi} \frac{d^{d-1}p}{(2\pi)^{d-1}} \frac{i  e^{- i p^0 (x^0-y^0) + i \vec{p} \cdot (\vec{x}-\vec{y}) }}{(p^0)^2 - (\vec{p})^2 - m^2 +i \epsilon}, $$
After performing the Wick rotation, $p^0 \to ip^0_E$, $d^dp=id^d p_E$, $p^2=-p_E^2$, $x^0-y^0\to i(x^0_E-y_E^0)$, the integral has the following form
$$ \int \frac{d^dp_E}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{ip_E^0(x_E^0-y_E^0)+i\vec{p}\cdot (\vec{x}-\vec{y})}}{p_E^2+m^2-i\epsilon}=\int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{ip\cdot(x_E-y_E)}}{p^2+m^2-i\epsilon}.$$

Switching to hyperspherical coordinates, we're left with
$$ \frac{\Omega_{d-1}}{(2\pi)^d}\int_0^\infty \frac{dp  p^{d-1}}{p^2+m^2}\int_{0}^\pi d\theta \sin^{d-2}\theta e^{-ip|x_E-y_E|\cos{\theta}}$$
where
$$\Omega_d=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}.$$

Applying a Schwinger parametrization of
$$ \frac{1}{p^2+m^2}=\int_0^\infty du e^{-u(p^2+m^2)},$$
we are left with
$$ \frac{\Omega_{d-1}}{(2\pi)^d}\int_0^\pi d\theta \sin^{d-2}\theta\int_0^\infty du \int_0^\infty dp p^{d-1}e^{-u(p^2+m^2)} e^{-ip|x_E-y_E|\cos\theta}$$

After $m\to 0$, the $p$ integral has the form
$$ \int_0^\infty dp p^{d-1} e^{-u\left(p^2-i\frac{|x_E-y_E|}{u}\cos\theta p\right)}$$

To make this into a Gaussian integral, we add and subtract $|x_E-y_E| ^2/(4u)\cos^2\theta$

$$\int_0^\infty dp p^{d-1} e^{-u\left(p-i\frac{|x_E-y_E|}{2u}\cos\theta\right)^2-\frac{|x_E-y_E|^2}{4u}\cos^2\theta} = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}{2u^{d/2}}e^{-\frac{|x_E-y_E|^2}{4u}\cos^2\theta}.$$

The total integral is now
$$ \frac{\Omega_{d-1}}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}{2}\int_0^\pi d\theta \sin^{d-2}\theta\int_0^\infty du \frac{1}{u^{d/2}} e^{-\frac{|x_E-y_E|^2}{4u} \cos^2 \theta},$$

and after using

$$ \int_0^\infty du \frac{1}{u^{d/2}}e^{-\frac{|x_E-y_E|^2}{4u}\cos^2\theta}=\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}-1\right) \left(\frac{|x_E-y_E|^2}{4}\cos^2\theta\right)^{1-\frac{d}{2}}= \Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}-1\right) \frac{|x_E-y_E|^{2-d}\cos^{2-d}\theta}{2^{2-d}},$$

we are finally left with
$$ \frac{\Omega_{d-1}}{(2\pi)^d} \Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}-1\right) \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}{2^{3-d}} \frac{1}{|x_E-y_E|^{d-2}}\int_0^\pi d\theta \tan^{d-2}\theta .$$

$\int_0^\pi d\theta \tan^{d-2}\theta $ has different values, for different $d$. The prefactor infront of the integral also does not give the appropriate values either, although atleast the dependence on $|x-y|$ is as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated, but at this point I would honestly like a complete and proper derivation of this relation, as I've spent a great deal trying to calculate it with no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We work in mostly positive signature. The scalar propagator is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G(x) &= \int \frac{d^D p}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{- i }{p^2 - i \epsilon } e^{ i p \cdot x } \\
&= \int \frac{d^{D-1} p}{(2\pi)^{D-1} } e^{ i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x} } \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dp^0}{2\pi} \frac{i}{ ( p^0 )^2 - | \vec{p}\, |^2 + i \epsilon } e^{ - i p^0 t } .
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We perform the integral over $p^0$ via contour integration. If $t>0$ ($t<0$), we close the contour down (up). The result is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dp^0}{2\pi} \frac{i}{ ( p^0 )^2 - | \vec{p}\, |^2 + i \epsilon } e^{ - i p^0 t } = \frac{  e^{ - i | \vec{p}\, | |t| }  }{2 | \vec{p}\, | } . 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We then have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G(x) &= \int \frac{d^{D-1} p}{(2\pi)^{D-1} } e^{ i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x} } \frac{  e^{ - i | \vec{p}\, | |t| }  }{2 | \vec{p}\, | } \\
&= \frac{\Omega_{D-3}}{2(2\pi)^{D-1}} \int_0^\infty d p p^{D-3}  e^{ - i p  |t| }  \int_{-1}^1 d z ( 1 - z^2 )^{\frac{D-4}{2}} e^{ i  p | \vec{x} | z } .
\end{split}
\end{equation}
In the second equality, we have moved to spherical coordinates and set $z=\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{x}$. The integral over $z$ gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-1}^1 d z ( 1 - z^2 )^{\frac{D-4}{2}} e^{ i  p | \vec{x} | z } = 2^{\frac{D-3}{2}} \pi^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma \left( \frac{D-2}{2}\right) (p|\vec{x}|)^{\frac{3-D}{2}} J_{\frac{D-3}{2}}(p |\vec{x}|) , 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $J_\nu(z)$ is the Bessel-$J$ function.

Plugging this back into the original integral
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G(x) &= \frac{1}{2(2\pi)^{\frac{D-1}{2}}}   |\vec{x}|^{-\frac{D-3}{2}}   \int_0^\infty d p p^{\frac{D-3}{2}}  e^{ - i p  |t| } J_{\frac{D-3}{2}}(p |\vec{x}|) . 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Finally, the integral over $p$ gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \int_0^\infty d p p^{\frac{D-3}{2}}  e^{ - i p  |t| } J_{\frac{D-3}{2}}(p |\vec{x}|) &=  2^{\frac{D-3}{2}} \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}} |\vec{x}|^{\frac{D-3}{2}} \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{D-2}{2} \right) }{ [ - t^2 + |\vec{x}|^2 + i \epsilon ]^{\frac{D-2}{2}} }  . 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Putting everything together, we find
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\boxed{ G(x) = \frac{1}{4\pi^{\frac{D}{2}}}  \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{D-2}{2} \right) }{ [ x^2 + i \epsilon ]^{\frac{D-2}{2}} }  . } 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: The solid angle factor should be $\Omega_{D-2}$, if we're going with my notation, but everything else ends up the same. Thanks so much!

Comment: The spacetime dimension is $D$. Spatial dimension is $D-1$. There are a total of $D-2$ angular directions. One of them (the angle between $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{x}$) is separated out. The remaining angular directions is $D-3$ dimensional so we have a factor of $\Omega_{D-3}$, _not_ $\Omega_{D-2}$.